# Как я могу по тегу(игрушки например) выцепить список координат объектов(или сразу отобразить), подходящих по этому тегу, из yandex или google map

Tags: javascript, python, api, map, yandex-geocoding-api

Как я могу по тегу(игрушки например) выцепить список координат объектов(или сразу отобразить), подходящих по этому тегу, из yandex или google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поисковый [провайдер 'yandex#search'](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl.html#searchControl__providers) позволяет искать организации. В том числе по их категориям. Результат сразу отображается на карте.

Пример реализации есть в песочнице: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo/

Comment: Спасибо, вам! А это бесплатно?

Comment: Условия бесплатного использования API Яндекс.Карт есть в документации: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html/